# Postfix [Courier, Maildir] Disable Quota

Tags: postfix, debian-squeeze, debian-wheezy, quota, courier-imap

I set up Postfix under Debian Wheezy with MySQL and virtual users using this [tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy). Thunderbird is recently giving me alerts "You exceeded your mail quota" and saving/moving emails is denied. The user I have set up in the users table in MySQL has a quota set to 0 (Zero). I would think the user has no quota.

I was experiencing the same under Debian Squeeze with a similar setup. In my current Wheezy setup, I actually omitted the quoata patch from the tutorial, to hopefully avoid this issue. I do not see any configuration anywhere that could possibly be overriding the MySQL user quota of 0. I am pretty sure I tried setting the quota to NULL with the same result. Instead of setting a really high quota, I would like to disable the quota alltogether.

BTW, an excerpt from my /etc/postfix/main.cf

> mailbox_size_limit = 0

Update, I am using Courier as the mail delivery agent and I have noticed the following file which might be setting the quota?:

/home/vmail/domain.com/username/maildirsize

> 51200000S
>
> 49536186          764

I haven't trusted myself yet in editing or deleting this file.

Comment: You are using postfix with which mail delivery agent? Dovecot? Courier? If dovecot, check "plugin" section on dovecot.conf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there are two components that check your quota:

- Postfix, the checking process was invoked when you receiving email.
- Courier, the checking process was invoked when you moving around the email via POP3 and IMAP.

Since you mention **Thunderbird who report the quota warning**, then likely you haven't disabled quota checking from Courier.

#### So, how to disable quota in Courier?

[At step 7 from your tutorial](https://www.howtoforge.com/virtual-users-and-domains-with-postfix-courier-mysql-and-squirrelmail-debian-wheezy-p2), you can configure courier via `/etc/courier/authmysqlrc`. In that file, you define

```
MYSQL_QUOTA_FIELD quota
```

You can disable quota by erasing/commenting out that line.

The next step is ensuring that [maildirsize file wasn't present in Maildir folder](http://markmail.org/message/ge3ymljvyz6jsldo).